# String to Integer error on file name

Tags: python, python-2.7, operating-system

I'm trying to add 59 to the 3 digits in a specific position in all the files in my folder, but it gives this error:

**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**

I have checked with prints, and is indeed a 3 char string, containing only digits(by the looks)

Code :

```
import os

def left(s, amount):
        return s[:amount]

def right(s, amount):
        return s[-amount:]

def mid(s, offset, amount):
        return s[offset:offset+amount]


for filename in os.listdir("V:\HD_RASTER\CTA2-GUA3"):
        s = mid(filename, 21, 3)
        print("Chars : " + len(s) + " String : " + s)
        s = int(s) + 59
        s = string(s)   
        os.rename(filename,left(filename,21) +  s + mid(filename,24,len(filename))
```

Folder screenshot of file names :

[image]

Comment: What is `s = string(s)` intended to do?

Comment: Your code works for me (manually entering a filename to test).  int(s) will give you the error you're getting if it's invalid.... it might be working on most of the files, but perhaps there's one in there with a different length?  And what kindall said (or asked).

Comment: @kindall turn it back into a string? unnecesary I guess but that's not the error

Comment: @Fhaab I printed the lenght and value of every "s", its a 3 len digit

Comment: you can use try/except to catch and print to see which part is wrong.

Comment: Can you give the exact filename it's first failing on?

Comment: No error for me either - except of the missing closing bracket at the very end.

Comment: wrap the `int(s)` statement in a `try..catch` block and print out diagnostics when it fails

Comment: actually, `string(s)` is not defined ... so this isn't exactly the code which is failing ... `str(s)` would be

Comment: This will only work if "V:\HD_RASTER\CTA2-GUA3" is the current directory

Comment: Instead of printing `s`, print `repr(s)` to make sure the characters are *exactly* what you think they are. Then do a copy/paste of the last value printed into the question so we can see what it's failing on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very fragile, and functions like `left`, `mid`, and `right` suggest you are more used to another language.

Among other things, this only works if your current directory contains the files, because `listdir` only returns the file name, not it's path. So `os.rename` will fail.

Try making it a little more flexible and bulletproof.

```
import glob
import os

FPATH = r"V:\HD_RASTER\CTA2-GUA3"
FILE_PREFIX= 'TRANS_leilao-004-14_0'
FULL_PREFIX = os.path.join(FPATH,PREFIX)
PREFIX_LEN = len(FULL_PREFIX)

files = glob.glob(FULL_PREFIX+r"???.*")
for old_file in files:
    n = old_file[PREFIX_LEN:PREFIX_LEN+3]
    try:
        new_n = int(n) + 59
    except ValueError:
        print "Failed to parse filename: " + old_file
        continue
    new_file = old_file[:PREFIX_LEN] + str(new_n) + old_file[PREFIX_LEN+3:]
    try:
        os.rename(old_file, new_file)
    catch OSError:
        print "failed to rename " + old_file
```